# Showing that a function has a zero in Unit Ball centred at 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, maximum-principle, entire-functions

Suppose that $f(z)$ is a non-constant entire function such that $$|f(z)|=1 \text{ for every } z \text{ with } |z|=1.$$

Then show that $f(z)$ does not have a zero in $\mathfrak{B}(0,1)$.

How I approached this one?

Define
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$$ for $z \in \mathfrak{B}(0,1)$

As $$|f(z)|=1 \text{ for every } z \text{ with } |z|=1,$$
we also have that $$|g(z)|=1 \text{ for every } z \text{ with } |z|=1.$$

Since $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic, they are continuous on $\frak{B}(0,1)$. Thus by the Maximum Modulus Principle, $|f(z)|$ and $|g(z)|$ must attain their maximum value on the boundary $|z|=1$ only.

Thus $|f(z)|<1$ for $z \in \mathfrak{B}(0,1) \text{ and } |g(z)|<1$ for $z \in \mathfrak{B}(0,1)$

By definition, $$g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)} \implies |g(z)|>1 \text{ for } z \in \mathfrak{B}(0,1) $$

Thus $|g(z)|=1$.
How do I complete this proof? Is there a contradiction here?

Comment: It seems that you're supposed to show that $f$ ***does*** have a zero in $\mathfrak{B}(0,1),$ and that you're assuming there is no such zero to derive a contradiction. Is this correct? If so, you've already obtained a contradiction. By Maximum Modulus Principle, you know that $\bigl|g(z)\bigr|<1$ for all $z\in\mathfrak{B}(0,1),$ but by definition of $g$ and by MMP on $f,$ you know that $\bigl|g(z)\bigr|>1$ for all $z\in\mathfrak{B}(0,1).$ Thus, $1<1.$

Answer (score 1):

The maximum is indeed attained at the boundary. We now have two possibilities:

1. $\bigl\lvert f(w)\bigr\rvert=1$ whenever $\lvert w\rvert<1$. But then, since $\lvert f\rvert$ is constant, it is a standard Complex Analysis statement that then $f$ itself is constant.
2. $\bigl\lvert f(w)\bigr\rvert<1$ for some $w$ such that $\lvert w\rvert<1$. Then $f$ attains its minimum at some $z_0$ with $\lvert z_0\rvert<1$. If $f(z_0)\neq0$, then $g$ attains its maximum at $z_0$ then.

Comment: When |g|=1 then we have |f|=1 is obvious for every z. Why we have to consider case 2?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You said that maximum is indeed attained at the boundary. Then you said that we have two possibilites. I cannot understand from where 2nd possibility " |f(w)|=1 for some $w$ such that |w|<1" came from?

Comment: I am sorry. It was a typo.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: actually much more is true, namely, all such functions are $\alpha z^n, n \ge 1, |\alpha|=1$

Comment: @Conrad What about $f(z)=\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}$?

Comment: not entire as per requirement; if you allow poles (or just assume the function defined on the closed unit disc only), then yes all such functions are finite Blaschke products

Comment: @Conrad Right. I missed that assumption.